# Creating a hosted repository via conduit

Tags: phabricator

I am writing a web app to be used internally for scaffolding out new projects.  As a part of this process I need to be able to create a phabricator repository over http (using conduit), and push the initial commit to it.  I've managed to create a repository using conduit's repository.create method, but I am unable to push to it as it is listed as 'hosted elsewhere.'

How can I created a repository that is hosted on phabricator?  Looking through the available options for repository.create I can't see anything to specify the hosting options, nor can I find any other helpful conduit methods.  This seems like such a standard task that I feel I must be simply missing something

Answer (score 0):

We landed [this diff](https://secure.phabricator.com/D9598) onto our local branch and then we use this snippet in a bash script to create them:

```
json='{"name":"'"$REPONAME"'","callsign":"'"$CALLSIGN"'","vcs":"git","hosting-enabled":true,"serve-over-ssh":"readwrite","uri":"git@hive.lan:'"$REPONAME"'"}'
echo $json
out=$(echo $json | $arc call-conduit repository.create)
# Check for an error
if [[ $out != *\"error\":null* ]];
then
  echo "Conduit returned an error!"
  echo ""
  echo $out
  exit 1
fi
echo "Created!"
echo ""
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the parameters 'hosting-enabled' and 'serve-over-ssh' dont work for us.  I get an error stating that the api method repository.create doesn't define these methods.  
I noticed a diff [here](https://secure.phabricator.com/D9598) which was not approved that implements these arguments, did you maybe manually implement these changes?

Comment: Yes.  I'm sorry that I had forgotten that.  Bluehawk used to work for us and  he landed that diff onto our local codebase.  I'll edit my post to include that.